# waterproof outdoor landing flooring

Tags: flooring, porch

The entrance to my house consists of a few steps leading to a small landing (45" x 72") with the front door of the house. The landing is exposed to the elements.

Since under the landing is my basement, I wonder what floor can I put on this landing, so that it is waterproof?  (Currently there is a pressure treated plywood covered by a worn-out outdoor capret and I would like to replace it by something nicer and more durable.)

Comment: Is the landing covered with a roof?

Comment: It was just a pressure treated plywood covered by carpet. I hope replace it by something nicer and more waterproof, as water was seeping to the basement.

Answer (score 1):

If the plywood is in good shape, paint it with a waterproofing membrane such as Redguard or Aqua-defense, available from bigbox stores. Apply at least 2 coats.
Then you can cover the surface with anything you choose.
( I read a story about a guy that coated the inside of a carboard box with redguard and filled it with water. It sat on his deck for a week without leaking!  This stuff really works.)

Answer (score 1):

I would think about separating the water proofing problem from having-a-nice-floor.

Decide what you want for your decking.  It doesn't have to prevent water from getting through, just has to be able to withstand the elements itself.  PT decking is a simple solution.

Then, on the underside of your landing, you attach a waterproof barrier, with a slight slope to it away from the house, to capture and divert water that makes it through the floor.  Something like a piece of corrugated plastic, cut to fit, like this (picture from Home Depot):
[image]

At the lower end of the down slope, you can add a rain gutter or gutter-like material to divert and dump the water to wherever makes the most sense.